# Sequence of bounded sequences converge uniformly to bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence, upper-lower-bounds

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of bounded functions on a set $S$, and suppose $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $S$. Prove $f$ is bounded on $S$.

By uniform convergence $\forall \epsilon \ \exists N>0 : \forall x \in S,n>N$
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$
By the reverse triangle inequality we can obtain
$$|f(x)| \leq |f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)| < |f_n(x)| + \epsilon$$

Since $\forall n, |f_n(x)| < M_n$

$$|f(x)| < \epsilon' = \epsilon + M_n$$

and $f$ is bounded on $S$.

Why do I need to fix $\epsilon$ if it is arbitrary?

Comment: No, because $M$ depends on $n$. Note thyat you haven't used that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Comment: I used that to bound the second term in the sum

Comment: I think your $M = \max\{M_1, M_2, ..., M_n\}$ should be $M = \max\{M_1, M_2, ..., M_N\}$. (Also, you might as well start by fixing $\epsilon=1$, say.)

Comment: I changed the whole thing, as well as adding the question with more detail

Comment: You don't _need_ to fix $\epsilon$. I thought it would make the proof simpler. (Also, your earlier version was closer to a valid proof.)